# Installation phpmyadmin

Tags: installation, phpmyadmin

The display of the phpmyadmin home page is not complete. I can't authenticate myself. The server on which I install phpmyadmin already has a web application that works very well

[page accueil phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXKxx.png)

Version phpmyadmin : phpMyAdmin-4.9.10

php : PHP 7.0.33-57+0~20211119.61+debian11~1.gbp5d8ba5 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2021 06:42:48) ( NTS )

OS : Debian11

apache : Server version: Apache/2.4.53 (Debian)

mariadb : Server version: 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 Debian 11

- I checked directory permissions issue : www-data owner
- I checked acccess.log

  *myip - - [12/Jun/2022:07:54:00 +0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=4.9.10 HTTP/1.1" 200 32517 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36"
  myip - - [12/Jun/2022:07:54:00 +0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/img/logo_right.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5969 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36"
  myip - - [12/Jun/2022:07:54:00 +0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/dot.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 1702 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36"
  myip - - [12/Jun/2022:07:54:00 +0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/css/printview.css?v=4.9.10 HTTP/1.1" 200 2737 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36"
  myip - - [12/Jun/2022:07:54:00 +0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 24209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36"
  myip - - [12/Jun/2022:07:54:01 +0300] "GET /phpmyadmin/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 24209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36"*
- I checked error.log
  no error
- I removed the ssl, but in port 80 same problem

Comment: Any errors in your browser when you access the page?

Comment: I had this error : Content Security Policy: Les paramètres de la page ont empêché le chargement d’une ressource à inline (« script-src »).

Comment: I add this in apche2.conf    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'"
</IfModule>  It good now. what is this line for?